# why get data from dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler: to late

Tags: objective-c

i have some misunderstands with completion Handler in 
- dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:.

TableViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender {
    if ([self.textField.text isEqual: @""]) {
        [self textFieldAnimation];
    } else {
        [self.dataWork takeAndParseDataFromFlickrApiWithTag:self.textField.text];
        [self.itemStore fillItemsStore:self.dataWork];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

when i call takeAndParseDataFromFlickrApiWithTag: i want to download some data from Flickr Api and then parse it and make array with JSON objects in dictionaries.

DataWorkWithFlickrApi.m

```
- (void)takeAndParseDataFromFlickrApiWithTag:(NSString *)tag {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSString *prerareStringForUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=%@&tags=%@&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", self.apiKey, tag];

    self.url = [NSURL URLWithString:prerareStringForUrl];
    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
    [[self.session dataTaskWithURL:self.url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSDictionary *photos = dict[@"photos"];
            self.array = photos[@"photo"];
       // NSLog(@"%@", self.array);
    }] resume];
}
```

when this method is finished i go to the next [self.itemStore fillItemsStore:self.dataWork]; but at this moment in my array i have 0 objects, and then when i used second time - (IBAction)search: just then my table view showed me a list with objects and i have in array 100 objects and in that time there is uploading a new hundred objects.

So questions is why loading data so late? why I just don't get the data as a method takeAndParseDataFromFlickrApiWithTag: finishes? How to fix it?

sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a completion handler is that it is called when the task is completed.

You need to trigger processing of the next item in your completion handler and not when `-takeAndParseDataFromFlickrApiWithTag:` returns.